# UNIX; merge two files with common words

Tags: bash, file, unix, search, replace

I have two files; file1.txt and file2.txt. And want to merge them like:

```
name1 note1
name2 note2
name3 note3
```

file1.txt

```
name2 note2_2
name3 note2_3
name1 note2_1
```

file2.txt

```
name1 note1 note2_1
name2 note2 note2_2
name3 note3 note2_3
```

result.txt

I did some code but I'm not sure how to append it.

```
#!/bin/bash

cut -d' ' -f1 file1.txt > names1.txt

while read -a rows
do
    for i in "${rows[@]}"
    do
    grep "$i" | cut -f 2- -d ' ' file2.txt > new.txt
    done
    *here I should append it (I think)*
done < names1.txt
```

I know that sed can be use for appending like; `sed 's/$/ *the first word of each line from new.txt*/' file1.txt`
Or using `paste file1.txt new.txt > fileresults.txt`

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts in form of code in your question. Could you please do let us know which columns you want to compare from both the files?

Answer (score 2):

[`join(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) is made for this sort of thing:

```
join file1.txt <(sort file2.txt) > result.txt
```

It does require that files are sorted on the join field (defaults to the first column), so if your real file1 isn't sorted, sort it the same way as file2 is in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sh
awk '{print $2}' file2.txt | xargs -I {} awk '$0=$0" {}"' file1.txt
```

- `awk '{print $2}' file2` reads the second column of `file2`.
- `| xargs -I {}` pips the stdout of the first `awk` into the next spot where `{}` appears. You could also choose other things as the place holder.
- `awk '$0=$0" {}"' file1` reads all columns of `file1` and puts the the `xargs` argument behind the whitespace.